# Perturbation theory and the accuracy of physics in real life scenarios

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, perturbation-theory

Back when I studying the time independent perturbation theory of the Hamiltonian in quantum mechanics, I remember reading that there are only three problems in physics with exact solutions: the free particle, the harmonic oscillator and the hydrogen atom.

It was further stated that any given problem (even a simple pendulum) could have its solution determined by applying a small perturbation to the exact solution of another similar problem, i.e., it would be an approximate solution.

So I was left wondering: are the solutions to all [a] real life scenarios (where you don't go around neglecting friction, using symmetries, etc.) obtained through perturbation theory? That is, are they all approximations and not exact solutions? In that case, would it be fair to state that physics is inaccurate to a certain degree?

[a] With the exception of the aforementioned ones.

Comment: I'd say you are completely right

Comment: This is a good question!  How many of these celebrated quantum field theory results in the Standard Model are only perturbative approximations?  I wonder whether there are *any* exact solutions to these theories and whether they hold at all in their exact form.

Comment: *"I remember reading that there are only three problems in physics with exact solutions: the free particle, the harmonic oscillator and the hydrogen atom."* The particle in a box is also exactly solvable. So is a particle in a cosine potential, which is exactly what you need to solve the pendulum. I'm sure there are more.